# Sort time based on current time

Tags: javascript, sorting, momentjs

I am trying to sort an array based on current time. Here is my array

```
[
   {
      "time":"10:00:00"
   },
   {
      "time":"10:30:00"
   },
   {
      "time":"13:30:00"
   },
   {
      "time":"14:30:00"
   }
]
```

I want to return an array where the closest current time would be on first index and then next close one (till the upcoming time) and the previous times are would be the last items. For example if the current time is `1pm` then the expected result would be

```
[
   {
      "time":"13:30:00"
   },
   {
      "time":"14:30:00"
   },
   {
      "time":"10:00:00"
   },
   {
      "time":"10:30:00"
   }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `10:30:00` is closer to 1pm that `10:00:00`

Comment: Sorry , I updated the question, I want upcoming closest time , not the previous one.

Comment: Can you change the time value to be seconds since midnight instead of a string version in 24 hour time? This would make a solution much easier to implement. Having the time values stored as strings introduces extra complications and slows down the solution.

Comment: Geuis , I think I can do that , but I am getting the above value from an API response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be better to use UNIX timestamps to represent time, you can do something like this:

```
var times = [
   {
      "time":"10:00:00"
   },
   {
      "time":"10:30:00"
   },
   {
      "time":"13:30:00"
   },
   {
      "time":"14:30:00"
   }
];

var currentTime = "13:00:00";
var sortedTimes = times.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.time < currentTime && b.time > currentTime) return 1;
    else if (a.time > currentTime && b.time < currentTime) return -1;
    else if (a.time < b.time) return -1;
    return 1;
});
```

As documented here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp